# trying to pass the value of a field to an external function inside the $addfields stage of aggregate fails

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have been trying without success to write a script which will update all documents in a database called "locations_copy". The gist is that each document will get an additional field of type object, which will contain two subfields: "utc" of type Date and "tz" of type string. "utc" will get its' value from each document's existing "timeUTC" field, while "tz" will receive the result of a subquery from a different collection extracts the "timeZoneID" of the owner of the current location, with "subjectID" being the foreign key.

My problem is that I don't seem to be able to find a way to pass the value of the field "subjectID" to an external function. Here is my code:

```
db.locations_copy.aggregate( [
   { $match: {"subjectID": {"$exists": true}}},
   { $addFields: {
       time: { utc: "$timeUTC",
               tz: { "$arrayElemAt": [get_location_doc(ObjectId("$subjectID")), 0 ] }}
       
     }
   }
] ).forEach(function(x){db.locations_copy.save(x)})
```

with "get_location_doc" being an external function that returns an array (don't ask why) with the element being what I need.

No matter what I try, the "$subjectID" I send to "get_location_doc" is parsed as a simple string, meaning it's translated as "$subjectID" instead of the underlying value of that field. When I replace that argument with a hard-coded ID, everything works just fine. I tried replacing "$subjectID" with simply subjectID (without quotes - in which case it was simply undefined), $subjectID (also undefined), "$$subjectID" (simple string) and pretty much every variation you can think of.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) aggregation operator.

Comment: $function is only available from mongo 4.4, and I'm working on 4.1

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are mixing the server and the client contexts.

Your function is executed on the client side (in `mongo` shell) prior to the aggregation query being sent to the server. The result of the function is incorporated into the query (rather than being evaluated per each matching document by the server).

To execute code on the server side, you need to use one of the provided MQL features like $function, $where or map-reduce.

Comment: Thank you. I can't use $function due to mongo version. Could you please show me how I could implement  $where or map-reduce in the existing query so that this would work?

Comment: Feel free to create a new question stating what you want to do query-wise.

Comment: Done:)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024107/updating-a-collection-from-a-different-database