# Updating a collection from a different database

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using Mongo 4.1 and would like to update a collection named "location_copy", by adding a new field to it of type object named "time", with two subfields: "utcTime", which will be populated by the value of that documents "time" field, and "tz", which will be populated by value of "subject.contactInf[0].addresses[0].timeZoneID" from of the document in the collection "subjects" in the database "Subjects" (a different database from the one of the first collection) with "_id" field value corresponding to "subjectID" field in locations_copy.

I have tried to accomplish this with the following code:

```
const get_time_zone_id = function(doc) {return doc.contactInfo[0].addresses[0].timeZoneID}
const get_location_doc = function(subjectID) {    return db.getSiblingDB('Subjects').subjects.find({"_id": subjectID, "contactInfo": {"$exists": true}, "$where" : function() {

   return (this.contactInfo.length > 0 && this.contactInfo[0].addresses && this.contactInfo[0].addresses.length > 0 && this.contactInfo[0].addresses[0].timeZoneID)
}}, {"contactInfo" : {"$slice": 1}, "contactInfo.addresses": {"$slice": 1},"contactInfo.addresses.timeZoneID" : 1}).map(get_time_zone_id)}

db.locations_copy.aggregate( [
   { $match: {"subjectID": {"$exists": true}}},
   { $addFields: {
       time: { utc: "$timeUTC",
               tz: { "$arrayElemAt": [get_location_doc(ObjectId("$subjectID")), 0 ] }}
       
     }
   }
] ).forEach(function(x){db.locations_copy.save(x)})
```

everything works except for one thing: when I try to pass ObjectId("$subjectID") as a parameter to "get_location_doc", it parses "$subjectID" as a literal string rather than passing the value of the underlying field in each document. I have also tried passing simply subjectID (without quotes) in which case it was simply undefined, or "$$subjectID" which led me to a literal string again. I understand this is due to client/server side parsing in run time.
I have tried to utilize the "$function" operator, but apparently it's only available from version 4.4 (I'm using 4.1).
I should note, that if I replace "$subjectID" with a hard-coded string ID (for example "5ff4c037bc0a716381231277") everything works as you'd expect.
Can anyone please help me accomplish what I intend? since this script is only meant to be executed once, performance is not much of an issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`db.getSiblingDB().collection.find()` is a client-side operation. It is not something you can use to join collections as part of a query. For that, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/.

The second thing you are doing is retrieving nested fields out of a document. You can do this with $set and dot notation. See specifically the example at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#adding-fields-to-an-embedded-document.

You will need to construct a single aggregation pipeline that does everything your current mix of aggregation and javascript does using only the operations documented in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ and the stages documented in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/.